# Crystal Report 8.5 Parameter Sorting

Tags: sorting, parameters, crystal-reports

We are using 8.0 version for our reports on most of our programs except for our Fax and Email modules where in the report must be converted to PDF. I believe export to PDF is not supported in 8.0. So we are using both 8.0 and 8.5.

My question is:

When I open a report created using 8.0 via the 8.5 designer, the parameters are sorted in alphabetical order. Is there a way to disable this in 8.5?

Comment: Where are the parameters sorted alphabetically?  The Field Explorer?  Somewhere else?

Comment: That's weird; I don't have CR 8.0 handy, but I created a new 8.5 repot, then created parameter `B`, then parameter `A`, saved and closed the report, re-opened it, and the parameters are still showing `B` first and `A` second.  I don't see any settings to manage this, so I'm not sure why yours is getting sorted; wish I could be more help.

Comment: i think if it's created with 8.0 then opened with 8.5.

Comment: What options do you have if you right-click the 'Parameters' node?

Comment: New, Show Field Type, Refresh, Cancel Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and it's really aggravating, but you're going to need to name your parameters alphabetically to make them show up in the order you want. You can give them different on-screen prompt text, but the actual parameter names will need to be in an alphabetic order. For example: Param01FirstName, Param02LastName, Param03StartDate, Param04EndDate